# python execute command line in a function

Tags: python, function, command, gpio, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want to implement this two GPIO commands into my function, but it gives me a syntax error. But I don't know how to organize it.

```
elif message_text == HI and term.term_started == False:
    fb.simple_msg(sender_id, gpio -g mode 17 out gpio -g write 17 1 )
```

Comment: you are not using the string quotation marks.

Comment: will execute the command that will open GPIO 17

Comment: will it execute via python? I mean, python does not seem to understand `gpio -g mode 17 out gpio -g write 17 1`, which results in the syntax error.

Comment: yeah, but I want to execute this gpio code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the code does, but here is my guess:

```
elif message_text == "HI" and term.term_started == False:
    fb.simple_msg(sender_id, "gpio -g mode 17 out gpio -g write 17 1")
```

at lease you won't get the syntax error if other variables like `sender_id` are defined appropriately. note that I changed

- `HI` to `"HI"` and
- `gpio -g mode 17 out gpio -g write 17 1` to `"gpio -g mode 17 out gpio -g write 17 1"`.